# If Conditional Statement Checking always check only the first condition in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've some checking condition with If..Then..Else.. statement but I've something happened that keep confusing me with this problem. My code was :

```
if ( !context.APIPOS_ExportPos.Any(x => x.CustomerRef == HAWBToUpdate) || !context.Export_Reguler.Any(y => y.CustomerRef == HAWBToUpdate) ) 
{
   //some complicated operation goes here...
}
```

It's always check the **first condition before OR Operator ( || )** and the condition after OR Operator was not checked.

What should I do to solve this problem ?  Many thanks for your help

Comment: You are using OR operator. So only one condition needs to be true. If the first condition is returned true then second condition will not be checked. Second condition will be checked only if the first one is returned false.

Comment: Please try to re-phrase your question so that it's clearer. It's not clear what your issue is.

Comment: If you you use AND operator both the condition will be checked and they both must be true to execute the code inside if block

Comment: If you use a single |  (OR) it will evaluate both even if the first is true. This is useful if  the second condition performs a necessary function. (but it's bad form)

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) for boolean logical operators? It should answer all your questions on the topic. Downvote for lack of research effort. Please clarify the question if there's something that the documentation didn't answer.

Comment: Can you describe in English when that condition should pass? I'm trying to find out whether you need an OR or maybe an AND there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use && instead of ||.
The problem of your code is that when a condition became true, it doesn't need to check further conditions.

Comment: But then if the first condition is `false`, it doesn't need to check further conditions. If OP wants both to be checked whatever happens, he may need to use `|` or `&` instead of `||` or `&&`

Comment: Yes that's true, but if you going to do something based on any condition became true, then why do you need to evaluate both. Isn't that just redundant. I mean the main thing is if anything is true, the whole thing is true.

Comment: It may be needed if what you are checking has side effects and you want those effects to happen